# input×gain higher than VCC

Tags: amplifier

I have an amplifier circuit. Is it a problem if the input×gain is higher than the VCC?

So at some moments I have 3.3 V on the '+' input. I see it caps to 11 V in my simulation but do I damage the component?

[image: Amplifier circuit]

Comment: Damage to components occurs when you exceed their **maximum ratings**, you find these in the component's datasheet. In your case the fact that the output "clips" means that it simply goes as far as it can go. The fact that "clipping" occurs is fine, it does not damage the opamp.

Comment: If you want to be thorough, compute the differential voltage in that circumstance and determine if it's outside of the device's operating parameters.  For that circuit, with most op-amps, the worst that'll happen *in that circumstance* is that it may be slow coming off of saturation when the input voltage goes down.  While you're at it, use a modern part: a 741 is practically an antique; when I was in college in the 1980's it was already something that was only used by hobbyists, EE labs, and paid hacks (as opposed to professionals) who had not yet gotten the memo.

Answer (score 1):

In short: probably not.

---

The datasheet of the component (if it is actually a decent one) will tell you when there is a high risk of damaging the component.

Those conditions are listed under "Absolute maximum ratings". Note that these values can be higher than the one listed for normal operation and you should not expect the component to work as expected outside the normal operation range. The only thing you can expect that there is no fatal damage to the component as long as you stay inside the absolute maximum ratings.

Typical values are temperature range, supply voltage range and input voltage range of the individual input pins (often with respect to the supply voltage). For outputs there is a current limitation (or a short circuit duration). And you find a total power consumption specification. And even more or less depending on the exact component.

---

**What about an opamp output?**

The opamp output stage is inherently limited to the supply voltage of the device. It cannot go beyond the positive or negative supply voltage even if the gain equation would require it to do so. How close it can get to the supply rails depends on the implementation of the device. Some swing to a few millivolts to the rails, others need a headroom of volts.

So by this alone you cannot damage the opamp output. What you should consider is the load to the output. Will the output current of your opamp stay below the limit imposed by the normal operation specifications?

Second consideration then is the power consumption of the opamp. Even if the output current is in the specification the total power consumption (or temperature rise) might be exceeded if you are working at the limit of voltage and current.

(You typically don't want to stress the component to the absolute maximum ratings)